# Pythonic way to append list of strings to an array

Tags: python

I'm new to Python and come from a Java background.  I'd like to know the most Pythonic way of writing this code:

```
entry_list = []
for entry in feed.entry:
    entry_list.append(entry.title.text)
```

Basically for each element in the feed, I'd like to append that element's title to a list.

I don't know if I should use a map() or lambda function or what...

Thanks

Comment: @pst that's no help at all.  i know how to write the code multiple ways, i'm asking for other people's advice for the best way to do it.

Comment: I could swear it covers all the methods below -- list comprehensions in particular ;-)

Comment: Right, it has a multitude of ways to approach the problem, including the one I took... I need advice for which one to choose.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

most pythonic code I can think of:

```
entry_list = [entry.title.text for entry in feed.entry]
```

This is a [list comprehension](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html) which will construct a new list out of the elements in feed.entry.title.text.

To append you will need to do:

```
entry_list.extend([entry.title.text for entry in feed.entry])
```

As a side note, when doing extend operations, the normally fast [generator expression](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0289/) is much slower than a list comprehension.

Comment: List comprehension. The list constructor is `list()`.

Answer (score 4):

With a little bit of trickery courtesy of a genex.

```
entry_list.extend(x.title.text for x in feed.entry)
```

Or just a LC if you don't need to keep the same list.

```
entry_list = [x.title.text for x in feed.entry]
```

Comment: for some reason, list comprehensions are faster than generator sequences for the `extend` functionality.

Comment: Makes sense. With a LC it can just reallocate the list all in one go, whereas with a genex it has to reallocate for each yielded value or so.

Comment: Thanks, I forgot about list comprehension

Answer (score 3):

Always use **List Comprehension** for concise expressions.

```
entry_list = [entry.title.text for entry in feed.entry]
```

If all that you want to do with the entry_list is to iterate over it again, you can use the **generator** expression

```
entry_list = (entry.title.text for entry in feed.entry)
```

Notice that the only difference is in using parenthesis. When using the generator format, the  entry_list is not populated and can save the memory. You will still be able to do things like

```
for items in entry_list:
    do something
```

and

```
''.join(entry_list)
```